# Is there a way to restrict users from accessing power BI dashboards but allow them to analyze via excel by connecting to underlying cubes?

Tags: powerbi

As per my research we need a Pro License for users to connect to underlying cubes in power BI via excel but was wondering if there is any other way(without a Pro License) that we can achieve this.

Comment: If by cube you mean PBI dataset then no,you'll need a PBI Pro license or Premium to access them via Analyse in Excel

Comment: Yes I mean PBI dataset. Thank you for your response.